# Is there any method to check parameter of view functions in python (Django)?

Tags: python, django

What I want:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@params(required=["arg1", "arg2"], optional=["arg3"])
def test(request):
    # if arg1, args not posted, abort 400 or something
    arg1 = request.data.get("arg1")
    arg2 = request.data.get("arg2")
    arg3 = request.data.get("arg3")
    # do something
```

I use the rest framework but it seems that there is only validator for serializer.

Comment: Using `request.data["arg1"]` will raise an error if it isn't set - maybe that's all you need?

Comment: @Shadow not exactly, it should return corresponding message to the user, such as {"message": "missing arg1"}

Answer (score 2):

Why not define a basic function somewhere and get called by view functions.

For example, validator code snippet here:

```
@staticmethod
def checkMandatoryParams(request, params):
    msg = "need param `%s`"
    for param in params:
        if param not in request.data:
            return JsonResponse({'retcode':1,'msg': msg})
```

Then, call this guy from view functions like:

```
def handle_test(self, request):
    ret = checkMandatoryParams(request, ['images','tasks','whatever'])
    # check ret to return or not , or you can even wrap the validator to return by case
```

By this way, you could define whatever validators.

Comment: Because I don't want to write `check ret to return or not` each time. It's convenient to abort the request in the decorator.

Comment: Sure, go ahead to wrap as a decorator:-)